# How to call web service in VC++ in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: web-services, visual-c++

I am new in creating window-form in Visual Studio 2015 and after designing the login page, I have to call web service while click on the "Submit" button functionality. But my problem is I don't know how to call web Service and how to work with that.

Comment: Thank you so much @halfer for correcting my post.

Comment: Could you give us more detail like which service you want to call and what you want to get?

Comment: @Jin I want to do it in VC++ and I want to call the WCF service.

Answer (score 0):

Well there used to be an "Add (web)Reference" command in earlier versions of vs. However, this seems to be gone, at least in 2015 with a c++ project.

However, svcutil (SrviceModel Metadata Utility) is still available to generate the metadata and proxies that you need.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank u for ur reply  @Thomas but actually I can't get this. As I said i am very new to this work. so is there any other way to call WCF Webservice? I have installed Curl in Visual studio 2015. So now how to do it with Curl Soap. Please help